# I can't get selected value in drop down list for ddldialyser, after changing dropdown dependant on patient centre

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

aspx snippet

```
Dialyser:  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlDialyser" AutoPostBack="true">
                                    
                               </asp:DropDownList>

         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDialyser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="What dialyser does the patient use?" ControlToValidate="ddlDialyser" Display="None" ValidationGroup="valGroup1" EnableClientScript="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

code behind

```
Protected Sub BtnSearchPatHD_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearchPatHD.Click
    ' dump data into controls
    Dim pd As System.Data.DataSet

    pd = Conn.dataSet("exec spr_searchPatientInfo '" & txtbxphdhno.Text & "'", "ruds")

    lblHDPID.Text = pd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PID")
    lblHDFN.Text = pd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Firstname")
    lblHDSN.Text = pd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Surname")
    lblHDCons.Text = pd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Cons")
    lblHDCentre.Text = pd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Centre")

    ' hd script elements
    Dim hd As System.Data.DataSet

    'concentrates
    Dim concentrates As System.Data.DataSet

    hd = Conn.dataSet("exec spr_searchPatientHDScript '" & lblHDPID.Text & "'", "ruds")

    ' change drop down list for dialysers and concentrates below depending on centre the patient belongs to

    ' dropdown menu changes

    If lblHDCentre.Text = "JCUH" Or lblHDCentre.Text = "HOME" Then

        ' blank cell - list item
        Dim liFirst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("", "")

        ' bind  drop down list
        Dim dialyser As Data.DataSet
        dialyser = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Dialysers WHERE Centre LIKE '%JCUH%' OR Centre LIKE '%HOME%'", "ruds")
        ddlDialyser.DataValueField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataTextField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataSource = dialyser
        ddlDialyser.DataBind()
        ddlDialyser.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)


        Dim concentrate As Data.DataSet
        concentrate = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Concentrates WHERE Centre LIKE '%JCUH%'", "ruds")
        ddlConcentrate.DataValueField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataTextField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataSource = concentrate
        ddlConcentrate.DataBind()
        ddlConcentrate.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)


    ElseIf lblHDCentre.Text = "NDC" Then

        ' blank cell - list item
        Dim liFirst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("", "")

        Dim dialyser As Data.DataSet
        dialyser = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Dialysers WHERE Centre LIKE '%NDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlDialyser.DataValueField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataTextField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataSource = dialyser
        ddlDialyser.DataBind()

        ddlDialyser.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)


        Dim concentrate As Data.DataSet
        concentrate = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Concentrates WHERE Centre LIKE '%NDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlConcentrate.DataValueField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataTextField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataSource = concentrate
        ddlConcentrate.DataBind()
        ddlConcentrate.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)

    ElseIf lblHDCentre.Text = "SDC" Then

        ' blank cell - list item
        Dim liFirst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("", "")

        Dim dialyser As Data.DataSet
        dialyser = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Dialysers WHERE Centre LIKE '%SDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlDialyser.DataValueField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataTextField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataSource = dialyser
        ddlDialyser.DataBind()

        ddlDialyser.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)

        Dim concentrate As Data.DataSet
        concentrate = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Concentrates WHERE Centre LIKE '%SDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlConcentrate.DataValueField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataTextField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataSource = concentrate
        ddlConcentrate.DataBind()
        ddlConcentrate.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)

    ElseIf lblHDCentre.Text = "DDC" Then

        ' blank cell - list item
        Dim liFirst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("", "")

        Dim dialyser As Data.DataSet
        dialyser = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Dialysers WHERE Centre LIKE '%DDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlDialyser.DataValueField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataTextField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataSource = dialyser
        ddlDialyser.DataBind()

        ddlDialyser.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)



        Dim concentrate As Data.DataSet
        concentrate = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Concentrates WHERE Centre LIKE '%DDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlConcentrate.DataValueField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataTextField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataSource = concentrate
        ddlConcentrate.DataBind()
        ddlConcentrate.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)

    ElseIf lblHDCentre.Text = "FDC" Then

        ' blank cell - list item
        Dim liFirst As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("", "")

        Dim dialyser As Data.DataSet
        dialyser = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Dialysers WHERE Centre LIKE '%FDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlDialyser.DataValueField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataTextField = "Dialyser"
        ddlDialyser.DataSource = dialyser
        ddlDialyser.DataBind()

        ddlDialyser.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)

        Dim concentrate As Data.DataSet
        concentrate = Conn.dataSet("select * from tbl_Concentrates WHERE Centre LIKE '%FDC%'", "ruds")
        ddlConcentrate.DataValueField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataTextField = "Concentrate"
        ddlConcentrate.DataSource = concentrate
        ddlConcentrate.DataBind()
        ddlConcentrate.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)


    End If



    If hd.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        ddlDNAR.ClearSelection()
        ddlDNAR.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("DNAR")).Selected = True

        txtbxAllergies.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Allergies")

        ddlTreat.ClearSelection()
        ddlTreat.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Treatment")).Selected = True

        ddlTreat.SelectedItem.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Treatment")


        Dim dialyser As String = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Dialyser")

        lblCurrentDialyser.Text = dialyser

      
        ' ddlDialyser.Items.FindByText(dialyser).Selected = True

        If IsDBNull(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Dialyser")) Then

            ddlDialyser.ClearSelection()

        Else

            ddlDialyser.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Dialyser")).Selected = True


        End If


        Dim dialysate As String = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Concentrate")

        lblCurrentConcentrate.Text = dialysate

        If Not IsDBNull(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Concentrate")) Then

            If ddlConcentrate.SelectedItem.Text = dialysate Then

                ddlConcentrate.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Concentrate")

                concentrates = Conn.dataSet("exec spr_searchConcentrate '" & ddlConcentrate.SelectedValue & "'", "ruds")

                lblNa.Text = concentrates.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Na")
                lblCa.Text = concentrates.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Ca")
                lblGlu.Text = concentrates.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Glu")
                lblPo4.Text = concentrates.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("p04")

            Else

                ddlConcentrate.SelectedValue = ""

            End If

        Else

            ddlConcentrate.ClearSelection()

            lblNa.Text = ""
            lblCa.Text = ""
            lblGlu.Text = ""
            lblPo4.Text = ""

        End If

        Dim prd As String = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PRD")
        ddlPred.SelectedItem.Text = Conn.returnResult("select Diagnosis from tbl_RRPRD where PredID = '" & prd & "'", "Ruds")
        ddlPred.SelectedValue = Conn.returnResult("select Code from tbl_RRPRD where PredID = '" & prd & "'", "Ruds")

        ddlDiab.ClearSelection()
        ddlDiab.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Diab")).Selected = True

        txtbxPDays.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Schedule")
        txtbxHrs.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Duration")
        txtbxDryW.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("DryW")

        ddlAccess.ClearSelection()
        ddlAccess.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Access")).Selected = True

        ddlTinz.ClearSelection()
        ddlTinz.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Tinzaparin")).Selected = True

        ddlTemp.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Temperature")

        ddlInfect.ClearSelection()
        ddlInfect.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Infection")).Selected = True

        ddlNeedle.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Needle")
        ddlLinelock.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("LineLock")
        txtbxArtLumen.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ArtL")
        txtbxVenLumen.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("VenL")

        ddlIronDosage.ClearSelection()
        ddlIronDosage.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("IronDose")).Selected = True

        ddlIronFrequency.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("IronFreq")

        ddlAranDosage.ClearSelection()
        ddlAranDosage.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AranDose")).Selected = True

        ddlAranFrequency.SelectedValue = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("AranFreq")

        txtbxComments.Text = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Comments")
        HFScriptDate.Value = hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ScriptDate")

    Else

        ddlDNAR.SelectedValue = ""
        txtbxAllergies.Text = ""
        ddlTreat.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlDialyser.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlConcentrate.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlPred.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlDiab.SelectedValue = ""
        txtbxPDays.Text = ""
        txtbxHrs.Text = ""
        txtbxDryW.Text = ""
        ddlAccess.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlTinz.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlTemp.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlInfect.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlNeedle.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlLinelock.SelectedValue = ""
        txtbxArtLumen.Text = ""
        txtbxVenLumen.Text = ""
        ddlIronDosage.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlIronFrequency.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlAranDosage.SelectedValue = ""
        ddlAranFrequency.SelectedValue = ""
        txtbxComments.Text = ""
        HFScriptDate.Value = ""

    End If


End Sub
```

I am having problem retrieving selected dialyser after changing dialyser drop down list dependant on patient centre, I want to ask how i can find selected value for dialyser.

this is the snippet i am having problems with below

```
If IsDBNull(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Dialyser")) Then
        ddlDialyser.ClearSelection()

    Else

        ddlDialyser.Items.FindByText(hd.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Dialyser")).Selected = True


    End If
```

Comment: How about a `Select Case` instead of all those `Else If`.

Comment: That is way to much code for a single method. A method should have a single purpose. Try separating this into separate methods.